# Extracting filename from existing field (Source)?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder, logstash-file

from the below source path, i want to get "servicename" as an another field. can someone please provide the example use case?

```
source path = "/var/log/companyname/servicename/example/test/testfile.log"
```

How can i give grok filters in logstash for this?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you seen the grok debugger?  https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: lookup "positive lookahead" in Regexp. Should get you going.